# How to show images in img tag inside an ng-repeat while using Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**My problem:**

I want to display a list of images, stored localy, using ng-repeat directive, but the images re not being displayed.

AngularJS version: 1.2.22

**The code:**

- Directory Structure:

  ```
  myapp/
    |--- common/
    |    |--- images/
    |         |--- image.png
    |
    |--- subapp1/
    |    |--- index.html
    |    |--- subapp1.js
    |    |
    |    |--- controllers/
    |    |    |--- SubApp1Controller.js
    |    |
    |    |--- views/
    |    |    |--- imageListView.html
  ```
- index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="SubApp1">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page" data-ng-view="">
    </div>

    <!-- Include required libs, models and controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/libs/angular-touch.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/SubApp1Controller.js"></script>

    <!-- App Module (main) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="subapp1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- subapp1.js

```js
// Instantiate the SubApp1 Module.
var subApp1 = angular.module("SubApp1", ["ngRoute", "ngTouch"]);

// Setting Controllers
subApp1.controller("SubApp1Controller",
        ["$scope", SubApp1Controller]
);

// Define the routes for the module.
subApp1.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "SubApp1Controller",
        templateUrl: "views/imageListView.html"
    }); 

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/home"});
});
```

- SubApp1Controller.js

```js
function SubApp1Controller($scope)
{
    /**
     *  Private Method: _run()
     *  The main function of the SubApp1Controller, where all the magic
     *      happens.
     */
    function _run() {
        // this variable will define which style will be loaded on the image list view 
        $scope.section = "subapp1";

        var imageSource;

        imageSource = "../common/images/image.png";

        // list of media elements to be displayed on the list
        $scope.mediaList = [
            {
                thumbnailPath: imageSource,
                imagePath: imageSource,
            },
            {
                thumbnailPath: imageSource,
                imagePath: imageSource,
            },
            {
                thumbnailPath: imageSource,
                imagePath: imageSource,
            },
            {
                thumbnailPath: imageSource,
                imagePath: imageSource,
            },
            {
                thumbnailPath: imageSource,
                imagePath: imageSource,
            },
        ];
    };

    // Runs the main method of this class
    _run();
}
```

- imageListView.html

```
<div class="grid-background"></div>

<header class="grid-header {{section}}">
    <div class="button-right"></div>
</header>

<ul id="grid" class="grid">
    <li class="grid-item" data-ng-repeat="media in mediaList">
        <img data-ng-src="{{media.thumbnailPath}}" data-src="{{media.imagePath}}"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Extra info:**

The images are not being loaded and no error message is printed in the console.

I opened the Web Inspector tool to see what was processed in the li element and it did not have the src attribute, see bellow:

```
<li class="grid-item ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="media in mediaList">
        <img data-ng-src="../common/images/image.png" data-src="../common/images/image.png" />
</li>
```

If I add the src attribute in the img element, it is loaded, but I get an error, see bellow:

```
<li class="grid-item" data-ng-repeat="media in mediaList">
    <img data-ng-src="{{media.thumbnailPath}}"
         data-src="{{media.imagePath}}"
         src="{{media.thumbnailPath}}"
    />
</li>

<!-- Error message printed in the console -->
GET file:///[ABS_PATH]/%7B%7Bmedia.thumbnailPath%7D%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I have read many posts and questions/answers about similar issues, but none of them worked for me. Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be an issue with Angular sanitizing the srv and by default considering the `file://` protocol unsafe. Try using an `http[s]://` url and see if it works.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For IMG tags and AngularJS, use just the **ng-src** attribute.

```
<img ng-src="{{media.imagePath}}" />
```

**{{media.imagePath}}** must contain the URL to the image, absolute or relative.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question.

I don't know what happened, but it started working. I removed the data- prefix as you suggested, reloaded the page and it worked, then I added the data- prefix again, reloaded the page and it still works.

This still a mystery for me, but it is working now.

About the data- prefix, I want to use it to keep an HTML5 valid code.

Comment: I think it is better to use just one attribute and do not mix data-ng-src, ng-src and src.