# How can I implement Bootstrap Carousal using Angular Ng-Repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have piece of static code of bootstrap carousal and I want to implement it with angular ngRepeat. I have a array of images. How can I achieve following code  format using loop throught images? I want to break images as group of three inside div with `item` class .Here is code

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <ul class="thumbnails text-center">
                            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#1">
                                <img src="abc.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a><span>Page 1</span></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#1">
                                <img src="abc.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a><span>Page 2</span></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#1">
                                <img src="abc.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive" /></a><span>Page 3</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <ul class="thumbnails text-center">
                            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#1">
                                <img src="abc.jpg" class="center-block" /></a><span>Page 4</span></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#1">
                                <img src="abc.jpg"class="center-block" /></a><span>Page 5</span></li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2"><a href="#1">
                                <img src="abc.jpg" class="center-block" /></a><span>Page 6</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: There are tons of carousel "angularizided"

Comment: I know there is a lot carousal example but I want to learn how can I use ng-repeat in this scenario?

Comment: @Brijesh Gandhi so u want to repeat item class depending on number of images?

Comment: @Flash - I have number of thumbnail images .In carousal with single frame , I have to put it in group of three . so I have to create html like above code.I have array of images and i don't get any idea that how can I create using ng-repeat in this case?

Comment: @Brijesh Gandhi i think its repeated question u can follow this example : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432730/images-not-being-loaded-in-img-tag-inside-an-ng-repeat)

Comment: @Brijesh Gandhi inside angularjs file u can add dependency like   `var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);`